# Efficient way to query more than 50 BigQuery projects data

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to write a query that fetches data from more than almost 50 different BQ projects.
I'm using union all but it's not an efficient way to write *'union all'* 49 times for 50 different projects. Is there any way to efficiently fetch data from all projects?

I used this query

```
SELECT '1' AS id
FROM `d-1.daataa.table`

UNION ALL

SELECT '2' AS id
FROM `d-2.daataa.table`
```

Comment: You can use SQL Makeup langugage such as DBT. Copy all tables  to one dataset (with the cloud shell `bq cp d-1.daataa.table d-all.newdatset.d1` ) and use `Select *, _table_suffix as id from ``newdataset.d*`` `

Comment: Yes but even copying has to be done for all projects so is there a way to copy tables from all projects at once instead of copying it for each project every time?